# Why Google App Engine is not getting the same content as my desktop app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I wrote a Java app which runs from my PC and got the complete content of the following url :
http://itunes.apple.com/nz/genre/music-alternative/id20?letter=N

But when I tried to get the content from the same url using Google App Engine, it didn't have the 3 columns of Artist lists in the center of the page, it just got the contents of the top and left side of the page, why ?

Could it be : it takes longer for the list to show up, so GAE just got the first part of the content and missed the rest of it ?

Answer (score 2):

It's highly unlikely that GAE is missing or discarding content. It's more likely that itunes is doing geolocation on the originating IP, and is feeding that in to a decision on what content to return to the 'browser'.